# Dart when to use the mirror API

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

This may be a silly question, so sorry for asking this, and fyi I'm new to this kind of stuff.

After reading the documentation about mirrors, I can only grasp that the mirrors API is just like copying some instance plus access to some method that I don't know when/why to use.

Anybody care to give me some pointers, some example would be nice.

Comment: One downside is the mirror api when used with dart2js can lead to increased code size. Using the mirror api makes it harder for dart2js to optimize code. I don't think dart2js support for the mirror api is fully implemented yet. In general it should only really be used when you need to dynamically inspect code structure at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirror API allows you to retrieve metadata about objects and types programmatically (during execution) and to execute methods on objects . It is similar to [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) in .NET or Java.

A typical example is implementing plugin support:

Let's say that you define an `IPlugin` interface and want to automatically register with your `PluginManager` an instance of each type that implements it, without need to explicitly register each new implementation. Sometimes you even don't know all the plugins in advance, e.g. if users can deploy their own plugins.

You could do it like this (*WARNING:* I have never used Mirror API, so this is a high level description based on API documentation, not a proper implementation):

- You first use `MirrorSystem.libraries` to get `LibraryMirror` instance for each library in that `MirrorSystem`
- Then for each `LibraryMirror` you use `classes` property to get `ClassMirror` for each class in the library
- For each `ClassMirror` use `superinterfaces` to get all implemented interfaces
- If any of the implemented interfaces is `IPlugin` you can create an instance of that class (`ClassMirror.newInstance`) and register it with plugin manager.

Without mirror API, you would not be able to enumerate all the types, find what interfaces they implement (without creating an object) or create an instance of a type that you don't know about in advance.

To be honest I am not sure what is the current state of mirror API in Dart, I believe that it is still not finished, but I might be wrong.